# Проблема с отображением картинок в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Всем привет. Дело вот в чем.
Пишу апп, в принципе ничего сложного. Отображение товара в мобилке. При первом запуске скачиваю базу с сервера, и потом по категориям отображаю товары в `ListView`.

Картинки загружаю при помощи `AsyncTask`, в адаптере, если их еще нет. Естественно при первом запуске нет ни одной, так что все скачиваются.
И вот тут начинается непонятное для меня.

Открывается категория, и в течении секунды-двух подгружаются картинки для видимых элементов. При скроллинге в `ImageView` других элементов сначала показываются уже загруженные, а потом те, что подгружаются следом(правильные).
Выглядит так - я скроллю, и вижу одни и те же картинки для всех элементов, которые заменяются другими, пока не загрузятся все. После чего все отображается как надо.

Вот код загрузчика.

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView image;
int productId = 0;
int catId = 0;
Core core;
String path = "";

public ImageLoader (ImageView image, int productId, int catId) {
    this.image = image;
    this.productId = productId;
    this.catId = catId;
    core = Core.getInstance();
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(core.context.getApplicationContext());

        String name = "";
        if(productId == 0) {
            name = "cat_image_" + catId;
        } else {
            name = "product_image_" + productId;
        }

        File dir = cw.getDir(core.images, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File image = new File(dir, name);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
            mIcon11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 1, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
        path = image.getAbsolutePath();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if(image != null) {
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    if(productId == 0) {
        //core.dbHelper.updateCatImage(catId, path);
    } else {
        //core.dbHelper.updateProductImage(productId, path);
    }
}}
```

Вот адаптер

```
public class ItemsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
Core core;

public ItemsCursorAdapter(Activity context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    core = Core.getInstance();
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    VHolder v = (VHolder) view.getTag();

    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    String sName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    v.name.setText(sName);

    int priceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("price");
    double dPrice = cursor.getDouble(priceIndex);
    v.price.setText(String.valueOf(dPrice) + " сом");

    int opriceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("old_price");
    double doPrice = cursor.getDouble(opriceIndex);
    v.oldPrice.setText(String.valueOf(doPrice) + " сом");
    v.oldPrice.setPaintFlags(v.oldPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("prod_id");
    int id = cursor.getInt(idIndex);

    int imageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("image");
    String imageUrl = cursor.getString(imageIndex);

    v.btn.setTag(id);
    v.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*int id = (int) v.btn.getTag();
            Core core = Core.getInstance();
            core.addToCart(id);*/
        }
    });

    int cacheIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("cached_image");
    int isCached = cursor.getInt(cacheIndex);

    int fileIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("device_image");
    String filePath = cursor.getString(fileIndex);

    v.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_image);

    String fileName = "SOME_PATH" + id;

    if (new File(fileName).exists()) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
        v.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        new ImageLoader(v.image, id, 0).execute(imageUrl);
    }
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, null);
    VHolder holder = new VHolder();
    holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_image);
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_name);
    holder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_price);
    holder.oldPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_old_price);
    holder.btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.product_item_buy);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}}
```

Проблема видимо в том, что я неправильно передаю `ImageView` в `ImageLoader`, но не могу понять как это исправить. Буду признателен всем, кто что-то посоветует.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот с экрана, не совсем понятно в чем проблема

Comment: к сожалению не получается.  выглядит так - есть некий список, в несколько экранов высотой. т.е. скролл можно делать. для него подгружаются картинки, в адаптере. при открытии категории , за пару секунд подгружаются первые несколько картинок. при скролле на других элементах вместо заглушек отображаются только что загруженные картинки для других товаров. через пару секунд заменяются на правильные.

Answer (score 1):

В `bindView()` адаптера перед загрузкой картинки назначайте `ImageView` локальную  картинку-заглушку (нейтральный фон какой-нибудь), загрузку проводите не напрямую в виджет, а в локальную переменную. Когда нужная  картинка полностью загрузится, назначайте ее в `ImageView`.

Смысл в том, что `ImageView` в адаптере не должен оставаться без контента в начале метода `bindView()`. Алгоритм `ListView`  устроен так, что если элементы айтема принудительно не устанавливаются для каждой позиции, то он использует значения из прошлых айтемов. Там идет переиспользование объектов для оптимизации

Comment: У меня в xml файле прописана картинка-заглушка из ресурсов, это не то же самое что в адаптере прописывать?

Comment: Нет. Адаптер повторно использует ранее созданные объекты для разметки. В них картинка из xml уже заменена на ту, что была  айтеме. Если при создании нового айтема не устанавливать принудительно, что требуется, то останется информация из прошлого айтема.

Comment: не помогло это, все по прежнему осталось.

Comment: pavlofff Вам правильно ответил. Попробуйте понять это на примере фона, а не загружаемых картинок, так проще. Вот часть моего ответа на похожую проблему, но с фоном: "Обязательно переустанавливайте цвет фона для объектов, которым Вы меняете его, для КАЖДОГО пункта списка, даже если там не надо менять его (т.е. он должен остаться по умолчанию). Андроидный бог слишком ленив, чтобы создавать задний фон для каждого элемента списка, а берет его с ушедшего из зоны видимости пункта для вновь появившегося. Поэтому при листании списка туда-сюда, элементы закрашиваются помимо Вашей грешной воли."

Answer (score 0):

В общем, решения не нашел, и от своего велосипеда отказался. Заюзал Picasso, все норм.